# How to Build a jQuery array and move to the php, then use it on a PHP Function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

```
$(".divclass").each(function() {
    Build An Array with all .divclass ID ( 
});

 ~~~~> POST with AJAX for page.php

PHP gets the array and then use the function with each result of #divclassID

require "phpfunction.php";

$array = array received from AJAX;

for each #divclassID => $key {
getFunction($key)
}

After, rebuild a json array and print this;
```

Text explication:

1º) For each .divclass, Build an array with all $(this).attr("ID"); (with ID of each .divclass)

2º) Send the array to page.php;

3º) page.php receives the array and use the phpfunction with each element ID Listed in array;

Please, It's possible?

Comment: What does `page.php` do?

Answer (score 0):

Create one page for client-side and write some jQ Code in your page:

```
$(function(){
    var ids = [];
    $(".divclass").each(function() {
        ids.push($(this).attr('id')); // Push into JS array
    });
    $.post('page.php',{ids:ids},function(){
        alert('Horay, the data sent');
    });
});
```

**page.php:**

```
 <?php
 require "phpfunction.php";
 $ids = $_POST['ids']; // The $ids contains array of ID as you expected
 ?>
```

is simple alright ? Do you ?

Comment: thank you, but I must use the array loop in PHP function